# Creating 'non-rectangular' clickboxes for links?

Tags: css

Is there a way to create non-rectangular clickboxes for links?

I only recall seeing one example years ago on a webpage where they had a triangle in one of the corners of the page where the rollover effect would only execute when within the actual triangle? Unfortunately that site has gone and I never looked at the source.

[image: Cursor Behaviour]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like a job for an image map. You could use a GUI editor like Dreamweaver and draw any polygon you would like and then convert it into an image map. This will spit out your code in the form of a map tag, and series of area tags that define the coordinates of each vertice of the polygon.

Or you can use an online service such as...

http://www.mobilefish.com/services/image_map/image_map.php

To accomplish the same task.